# Why do we inherit from the component class in decorator pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

In the decorator pattern, the decorator class inherits from the component class and has an aggregation relationship with it. Well, the aggregation relationship is logical, but why should we inherit from the component? This pattern is supposed to decorate the component, so why does it need to inherit from it? If we have a component object in the decorator, we can add new functionalities to our class at runtime as we want, but I don't understand the inheritance.

[uml photo](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dofactory.com%2Fimg%2Fdiagrams%2Fnet%2Fdecorator.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dofactory.com%2Fnet%2Fdecorator-design-pattern&tbnid=2HN4kP74x2eYfM&vet=12ahUKEwizivCykJP9AhVNQfEDHeIYDOEQMygDegUIARDKAQ..i&docid=Yc6UbsXAhle3NM&w=431&h=356&q=decorator%20pattern&client=firefox-b-d&ved=2ahUKEwizivCykJP9AhVNQfEDHeIYDOEQMygDegUIARDKAQ)

Comment: Notice the writing in italic of Component and Decorator in the picture. They are just meant to be interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorator should implement the interface, but it doesn't have to inherit from the specific implementation. We should be able to use the decorator instead of the decorated component, but we should have a dependency on interface, not the specific class.

Comment: I just realized that the interface should be inherited, but why should the decorator be a child of the component? What is wrong with being a separate class?

Comment: It shouldn't be a child of component. If you look at the diagram https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#/media/File:Decorator_UML_class_diagram.svg you will see that Decorator and ConcreteComponent have common parent, which is the interface.